# How split data in a particular value

Tags: php, html, sql

I want to develop a stack system the description is as follow
Suppose we have  a data table
`Slip No.     Bags       Netweight      stack no
1234         260         456842.00       ?
1234         560         556842.00       ?  ...so on`

i want that an user via php form enter the values and the system works that it transfer the bags no. in stack if the stack is full or to be full then it show the remaining bag no.

Comment: your question is ambigous ,more explanation

Answer (score 1):

Is this a homework? If not, I don't see your problem:

```
quantity = x;
storage = 2800;
number_of_boxes = ceil(quantity/storage);
```

This is basic math

Comment: Actually i am a employee where i need to develop a web application the work of application is i have a data says  Slip No. (Given) , Bags(given), Net weight(given and calculate)  average weight (Net weight given /No. of bags)  i Just want an user enter the vaues and get the result. the web app in php

Comment: Then rewrite your question. What are you struggling with? What is the main problem there?